# Не получается скачать в google chrome, а в firefox все нормально

Tags: php

Делаю файловый менеджер для загрузки и скачивания файлов, есть проблема почему то файлы (папки) не получается скачать в google chrome, за то в  firefox все нормально. 
Сам метод лежит в файле class.php

```
public function resumableDownload(
    $file, 
    $filename, 
    $file_size, 
    $content_type, 
    $disposition = 'inline'
) {
    set_time_limit(0);
    session_write_close();
    // turn off compression on the server
    ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

    $time = filemtime($file);
    $etag = md5($file.$time);

    $fileopen = fopen($file, "rb");

    // Download speed in KB/s
    $chunk = 8*1024;

    // Initialize the range of bytes to be transferred
    $start = 0;
    $end = $file_size-1;

    // Check HTTP_RANGE variable
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']) 
        && preg_match('/^bytes=(\d+)-(\d*)/', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $arr)
    ) {
        $start = $arr[1];
        if ($arr[2]) {
            $end = $arr[2];
        }
    }

    // Check if starting and ending byte is valid
    if ($start > $end || $start > $file_size-1) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable");
        header("Content-Length: 0");
        return false;
    } else {
        // For the first time download
        if ($start == 0 && $end == $file_size) {
            // Send HTTP OK header
            header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        } else {
            // For resume download
            header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
            header("Content-Range: bytes ".$start."-".$end."/".$file_size);
        }


        //print_r($left);die;

        // Bytes left
        $left = $end-$start+1;

        //set last-modified header
        header('Last-Modified: '.date('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', $time));
        //set etag-header
        header('ETag: "'.$etag.'"');

        // Send the other headers
        header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
        header("Content-Length: ".$left);
        header("Content-Type: $content_type");
        header("Content-Disposition: $disposition; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Expires: -1");
        // Read file from the given starting bytes
        fseek($fileopen, $start);



        while (!feof($fileopen)) {
            echo fread($fileopen, $chunk);
            @ob_flush();
            flush();
            $left-=$chunk;
            // // Delay for 10 microsecond
             usleep(10);
        }
    }
    fclose($fileopen);
    return true;
}
```

Проверял каждую переменную, аналогично отображает как в google chrome, так и в firefox, не могу понять почему не работает в google chrome?

Comment: Уберите экранирование `\G\M\T`. И заголовок `Expires`. На другом компьютере пробовали хромом качать файлы?

Comment: вы уверены что хром не блокирует какое-нибудь всплывающее окно загрузки, если ссылка на скачивание файла открывается в отдельном окне,к примеру?

Comment: Все убрал, на  другом компе тоже не получаться пишет Ошибка файл не найден.

Comment: В хроме снял блокировку на всплывающие окно,  пишет Ошибка файл не найден

Answer (score -1):

Поскольку отсчет начинается с нуля, то замените условие в строке

```
if ($start == 0 && $end == $file_size)
```

на

```
if ($start == 0 && $end == $file_size-1)
```